# Export PNG with cytoscape function cy.png does not include popper.js labels

Tags: png, cytoscape.js, popper.js

I have tried to export the PNG related to the graph provided as sample for the integration of popper.js with cytoscape.js, but the exported png does not include the popper content when exported.

The reference sample is: https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape.js-popper/

The refence code to export the PNG is the following one:

```
                var text = window.cy.png({'output': 'blob'});
                var name = "test.png";
                var type = "image/png";
                var a = document.getElementById("downloadpng");
                var file = new Blob([text], { type: type });
                a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                a.download = name;
                a.click();
```

[This is the resulting image when exporting cy.png() included a popper.js content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krf8X.png)

Comment: This image is the result from exporting

Comment: Congratulations, I think you found a new issue :D The export doesn't work for me either, feel free to open a issue on github, seems like this is not a feature yet...

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is the expected behavior: image export in Cytoscape.js takes the Cytoscape.js canvas and exports it as image. The popper.js labels are not in the canvas - they are separate div objects in the DOM. Hence they are not included in the exported image.

Comment: Yes, and the content should be canvas or svg in order to make combining overlay images with the graph image possible.